# Add trigger to lambda function automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, triggers, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I managed to deploy a AWS Lambda function using Travis, however I also need to add a trigger to it (in my case it's Kinesis). Has anyone done it? If there is no out of the box way to do it with travis I suppose I need to add the script using AWS CLI? Anyone has done it and could share some advice or where I could take a look as reference?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted primarily to add the trigger with Travis but Terraform makes it much simpler.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_event_source_mapping.html

So I can create my IAM roles, Kinesis Stream and the event mapping between Kinesis and Lambda using terraform https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_event_source_mapping.html

If you have any different ways that you believe is better, please do not hesitate in adding here. Thanks.